# Include required API contract calls automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, suman

I have this code:

```
  function runAsync(fn: Function) {
    ret.count++;
    fn(function (err: Error) {
      err && console.error(err.stack || err);
      ret.count--;
      if (ret.count < 1) {
        ret.cb();
      }
    });
  }

  s.on(events.FATAL_TEST_ERROR, function (val: any) {

    runAsync(function (cb: Function) {

      db.serialize(function () {
        db.run('CREATE TABLE lorem (info TEXT)');

        let stmt = db.prepare('INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (?)');
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          stmt.run('Ipsum ' + i);
        }
        stmt.finalize();

        db.all('SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM lorem', function (err: Error, rows: Array<any>) {

          cb()
        });
      });

    });
  });
```

what's happening is that if the user wants to include asynchronous calls, they need to call the runAsync function, and then place their code in the function body that's passed to runAsync.

Is there any way I can make this more automatic so that the user has to worry less about conforming perfectly to the API?

My primary concern is that the runAsync function has to be called in the same tick as the call to the event handler. My other concern is that it's all too common for API users to forget to fire callbacks.

Comment: Callbacks are lower level and more generic

Comment: I will add important details that I forgot to mention in the op

Comment: But I will take your advice and create a promise variant of the above. If they pass a callback then use the cb interface, no cb and we use promise interface, standard stuff.

Comment: As I indicated in the last part of the question  - what I want to do is somehow enforce that the call to runAsync is the first call in event handler function - is there some clever way to do that? I need to make sure runAsync is called in the same tick of the event loop.

Comment: Disagree on promises. The async library is more powerful than promises. RxJS and observables are also more powerful than promises. You are not talking to a fan of promises :)

Comment: Well right now the API function is just the callback from an event emitter. What I could do is pass in a subclass of event emitter, and create an onAsync method, which will call the runAsync function.

Comment: In this case I have to interop with event emitter api, using callbacks is more straightforward. In the end I have to flip a boolean and fire a callback. What I am doing here is allowing for asynchronous reporters. With Mocha we can only have synchronous reporters, but with Suman we can have async reporters. I havent fully expored, but if you havent used async.autoInject then you just don't know. I didn't discover async.autoInject until a month ago, super powerful stuff.

Comment: I wonder if the NPM sqlite3 library can handle promises

Comment: @jsfriend00 here is some interesting reading on promises - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs

Comment: http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.html

Comment: you will notice that both sqlite3 and selenium webdriver for JS both avoid promises and use a pretty clever approach to async code.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider to use promises: https://www.promisejs.org/

Comment: read about promises here - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs and here - http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.html